# How to properly initialize variable in Eclipse BPEL designer Apache ODE engine?

Tags: eclipse, apache, bpel

I have a simple BPEL variable of int datatype. The process gets deployed, but on execution, the ODE engine complains that the “variable counter isn’t properly initialized”. 
What is wrong with the below initialization code?

```
<bpel:variable name="counter" type="ns1:int">

<bpel:assign validate="no" name="setVariables">

<bpel:copy> <bpel:from><bpel:literal xml:space="preserve">1</bpel:literal>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to variable="counter"></bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy> </bpel:assign>
```

Comment: does skipping the `literal` part, using: `<bpel:from>1</bpel:from>`, help?

Comment: No. I am afraid not. :(

Comment: Ok, strange. Are you sure the variable isn't used before it's initialization? You could try initializing it on definition: `<bpel:variable name="counter" type="ns1:int"><bpel:from>1</bpel:from></variable>`. Moreover, I assume that `ns1` is XML Schema, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take the working solution from the comments to the question and provide it as answer, so that the question can be recorded as answered.

The problem can be solved by initializing the variable on its definition and not via a later `assign` during process execution. That way, the variable is guaranteed to be initialized on its first access. Default initialization for the variable at hand looks like this:

```
<bpel:variable name="counter" type="ns1:int"><bpel:from>1</bpel:from></variable>
```

Comment: This is pretty surprising because ODE does not support the inline from-spec in variable declarations, a patch is, however, available. Unless it's not a patched version, this statement should actually just do nothing.

Comment: Interesting :) ODE seems to be capable of more than you know? In the end, only @Monika Schubert can tell. Maybe, she kept both, the default initialization and the initialization in the assign, and the error was caused by something totally different which she fixed in between?